# How to handle network access from volley onResponse method

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-volley, picasso

I am trying to construct a BottomNavigationBar by fetching instructions from api server.

**Currently the code throws [java.lang.IllegalStateException] because it is calling Picasso from onResponse method.*

```
void updateMenuItems(RequestQueue queue, Menu menu){
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/menuIcons";

    //Request a string response from the provided URL
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null
            , new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e("updateMenu", response.toString());

            List<MenuItems> menuItemsList = new ArrayList<MenuItems>();

            for(int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonItem = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String imageLink = jsonItem.getString("image");

                    menu.add(0,
                            jsonItem.getInt("id"),
                            jsonItem.getInt("id"),
                            jsonItem.getString("name")).setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Picasso.get().load(imageLink).get()));

                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("updateMenu","response error");
        }
    });

    queue.add(jsonArrRequest);
}
```

JSON file the server is sending is as followes

```
app.get('/api/menuIcons', (req,res) => {
  res.send([
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Home',
      'url': 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/',
      'image': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/1200px-Home_Icon.svg.png"
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'Dashboard',
      'url': 'http://google.com/',
      'image': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/1200px-Home_Icon.svg.png"
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'name': 'Alarm',
      'url': 'https://google.com/',
      'image': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/1200px-Home_Icon.svg.png"
    },
    {
      'id': 4,
      'name': 'Setting',
      'url': 'http://google.com/',
      'image': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/1200px-Home_Icon.svg.png"
    }
  ]);
});
```

So here's the problem. I can add menu items with no icons with one Volley request.
However, to add image icons to the menu items, I need to access the image URL, which requires another asynchronous thread.

I don't want to declare another volley call inside volley call(it's just messy).
I would like to know if there is a structurally better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that network connection from onResponse method was not allowed since onResponse method is running in UI thread. Instead, I implemented
GsonRequest
class and modified parseNetworkResponse inside it. Since parseNetworkResponse is running in a separate thread, I could run other synchronous network requests within the function.